# Why is my neural network not learning?

Tags: keras

I am using the Keras library (with Python 3.6) to create a neural network.

My network maintains a constant overall maximum accuracy of 62.5%, over 16 training samples.

In what ways can I increase this accuracy?

Should I increase the number of training samples, or will restricting some of the data in the training samples help? Or something else that I might not know of?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here are the layers of my neural network:

```
# Build neural network
# Neural net with multiple layers
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=17, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(64, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(4, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit model
history = model.fit(X, Y, validation_split=0.46, nb_epoch=150, batch_size=3)
```

Comment: What is your data? What is your output?

Comment: @BlindKungFuMaster My input is a list of 17 values (some are binary, others are floats), my output is a 0 or 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**A neural network is the wrong approach for a problem with a small training set.** Even if you only have 2 features that are very representative of your function then 16 feature are not sufficient.

As a very general rule of thumb I use 100 examples for each feature in my dataset. This then increases exponentially with every single different class you expect. 16 instances is not enough to train a neural network. You will always have huge error margins when applying your model on a testing set. Even more problematic is the fact that you are using a very deep neural network. This will require even more training instances to properly learn the function.

I suggest you use a general machine learning technique such as **SVM**. This will likely result in better result. Try these techniques instead and see what results you get: k-NN, kernel SVM, k-means clustering.

But, be warned 16 training instances is still very little.

Comment: I do think that is my case. I'll work on my neural net and I'll get back as soon as I get some results

Comment: @Larry Your network is too wide. You are making your model too complex. Try removing some dense layers and introducing dropouts. Also, your validation split is too high. You have too less training examples and even then you are throwing almost 50% of the data for validation.

Answer (score 1):

First if your goal is to make a classification change the last sigmoid with softmax.

If you are performing regression add some dropout layers, increase number of training examples, change the optimizer, try to change the ReLus with sigmoid or tanh, try a different normalization technique for your input data.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a table with variables inside which you can call for, due to that you can also remove a variable a replace it with a new one.
So your program will have an organized table system which the size can be infinite.

With your library it could be repeatedly calling:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=17, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(64, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(4, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
```

have you checked that? or the library might need more variables to run. Have you tried to make a variable per layer for backups?